# Creating multiple lines from points to run to one central point in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I want to create lines coming from each individual 'place' and make all of the points meet at the first cell the place marked as 'OKC'. I already have the points marked on my map however, I am struggling to create lines from each location and make them meet at OKC. If needed I can open up this table if I need to add special fields to the data.

This is my table of coordinate data:

OKC
x=35.3892
y=-97.6007

ATL
x=33.63672
y=-84.419853

BWI
x=39.1811298
y=-76.668468

DEN
x=39.861656
y=-104.673178

HOU
x=29.6455555556
y=-95.2788888889

LAS
x=36.114647
y=-115.172813

MDW
x=41.7867758999999
y=-87.7521884

PHX
x=33.434278
y=-112.011583

STL
x=38.89028
y=-90.04611

EDIT:
To rephrase the way I am putting things. What I am wanting to do is make all of the points around the United States connect to the point in Oklahoma City using lines. I have added an image of my map (though its not the best photo, I think you can see what I mean now).
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's quite not clear what you want to achieve, maybe a screenshot of your map help. Through the explanation, if you want to convert your points to lines, you can use the points to lines GP tool. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm

Comment: Can you copy paste the table as text to your question

Comment: yes I can, one moment.

Comment: I sent it in the submission. Sorry the spacing is a little bit off.

Comment: You only have 9 cities that need to link to OKC, why don't you simply draw the line? It will take 1 minute to do that? Suggest you read the help file on editing.

Comment: This could also be done with a combination of `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` (on the points) and `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` (constructing `arcpy.Linestring` from the `firstPoint` of the `PointGeometry` to a static `Point` for OKC). The code samples in the documentation have 95% of what you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  You can use the XY to Line tool and some creative data management.

In the attribute table of your points file, make sure you have X and Y as columns with lat/long values.  If you don't have these fields you can just use the "Add XY coordinates" tool to automatically do so.

Then just manually create two more columns in the attribute table using the "add" function-- one for "TO_X, and one for TO_Y."  these will contain the same value for every point in your table-- these values will be the X Y coordinates of the single point you want to connect to.  Then when you run the XY to line tool just make the Start values the fields containing the original point data, and make the End values the column with the same repeating value for that central point